# how to get from previous for loop value(hard to title)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Hey guys I am newbie in Python , hope for some help here :)

My question is how to make for loop like this :

```
for x in range(5):
    print x + value which i got in previous loop
```

Maybe I am not super clear here so I will try to explain

for loop is going to print for me numbers 0,1,2,3,4 , right?
So what i want is every time it will print a value for example "3" it will plus previous one which in this case "2". Anybody can help me to explain how to do that ?

I am newbie in coding , so please be easy on me :D

Thank you!

Comment: print x+x-1? This should work.

Comment: If you want to accumulate results, use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce)

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. Please tell us more about the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @O.Suleiman This will be wrong for the first iteration.

Comment: A "better" approach would possibly be to iterate over 2 ranges simultaneously: `for x, y in zip(range(5), range(1, 5)): print x + y` but unless we know what *exacly* you are trying to achieve we can't help more than that

Comment: What should be printed on the first run through of the loop, when there is no previous value?

Comment: @DeepSpace OP didn't mention the scenario for the first run.

Comment: I see, sorry guys that  I wasn't clear , it was my first question online , so I am still figuring out how to that better. My goal is to get something like this : for i in range(5): print x=1.0/5.0/2.0 and print y= previous x + 0.2, so the asnwer should be like 0.1 , 0.3 , 0.5 , 0.7, 0.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your range list in a variable to be able to access it and enumerate to get indices, in case of value is different from indices:

```
rlist = range(5):
for index, value in enumerate(rlist):
    if index == 0:
        print value
    else:
        print value + rlist[index-1]
```

Comment: Thanks I think I got the idea how to do that, it was my first question online , so I understand I didn't make it clear :) It's very sad that some people downvoted your answer .

Comment: @VladlenAfanasjev If it helps, this is the most important ! Welcome here